# Error: "DataframReader" object is not callable

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

Here i am trying to read snappy.parquet file from ADLS, while doing it I am getting below error.

```py
input_file_path="/mnt/......./"

df=spark.read.format("delta"(input_file_path+'filename.snappy.parquet')

df_count=df.count()
display(df_count)
```

Please advice

Comment: Please be more clear on what you are doing and what is the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a syntax error - you're missing `load`:

```
df=spark.read.format("delta").load(input_file_path+'filename.snappy.parquet')
```

Plus another error is that you're trying to load an individual file with `delta` format - it doesn't work with individual files, but with the whole folder. If you need to load a single file (for some unknown reason), then you need to use `parquet` file format.

Comment: Yeah., agree, I said the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in code, one is missing load statement another is reading in a wrong way, so follow below

You need need to specify the parquet format if you are ready from parquet file format, which you are using in your code

```
df=spark.read.format("delta").load(input_file_path+'filename.snappy.parquet')
```

If you need to read from delta table, specify like this

```
df = (
    spark
    .read
    .format("delta")
    .load("yourfolder/")
)
```